# At what point in the election process must someone aspiring to be president meet the requirements established in the constitution?

Tags: united-states, presidential-election, constitution

US Representative Alexandria Ocasio-Cortez will reach the constitutionally required age to be eligible for presidency mere weeks before the 2024 Presidential elections. This means she definitely is eligible on the inauguration day in late January, and on election day itself, but she would be slightly younger than required during most of the early voting and mail-in ballot voting period, and she would definitely be under the legal requirement during the primaries and the official nomination event of her party.

So the question is: at what point must a presidential hopeful meet the constitutional requirements for eligibility for President?

Comment: I have a feeling the answer is "we don't know until someone tries, someone else sues, and the supreme court rules one way or the other"

Comment: @Caleth there is precedent related to Senators: Joe Biden was elected as Senator when he was too young but reached the age of 30 before he was sworn in. The question is whether that precedent would be enough to be able to apply the same thought process to the POTUS.

Comment: @Nzall The Supreme court has just shown that even a half-a-century old precedent (like Biden election to senatorship) can be overthrown.